# Integral with a gamma functions inside

Tags: probability, integration, gamma-function

I have a function based on the binomial distribution,

$$f(x;n,p)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} |x-i|\binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.$$

It's not so hard to plot this out with discrete points, but I'd like to smooth it as a continuous function.

So, for that, I should be moving to an integral. I will worry about the exact integral I want to use later, but I imagine I will have something of form similar to

$$h(x;n,p)=\int_{u=0}^n |x-u|\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (u+1) \Gamma (n+1-u)} p^u (1-p)^{n-u} \:du$$

$$= C_n \int_{u=0}^n |x-u|\frac{p^u (1-p)^{-u}}{\Gamma (u+1) \Gamma (n+1-u)}  \:du.$$

Is there any hope of dealing with these gamma functions? I understand most of these kinds of problems rely on cleverly applying some identities. Affine transformations are fine too if that will make things easier, but I'm having trouble here.

Thanks

Comment: Presumably your $i$'s should be $u$'s in the integrals.